# Firebase Crashlytics

Tags: firebase, ionic3, crashlytics

I want to integrate Firebase Crashlytics with my Ionic app. Looking at the documentation I find that the librbary is present for Android and iOS but I did not find any module for Ionic apps(Hybrid Apps). I found the native plugin for Firebase as @ionic-native/firebase and I need the same native plugin for Firebase crashlytics.

Can anyone please help?

Thanks

Comment: This plugin brings push notifications, analytics, event tracking, crash reporting and more from Google Firebase to your Cordova project! Android and iOS supported. It says in the doc :https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/firebase/

Comment: Thanks. I think for now you'll need to follow the Fabric Crashlytics workaround: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/fabric-io-w-crashlytics-setup/42307 -- Firebase Crashlytics is not yet part of that resource.